# While loop keeps going past counter?

Tags: python, while-loop, counter

I am just trying to write a simple loop to give me a list of prime numbers. I don't understand why the loop doesn't stop when the count reaches the set value.

```
def factors(n):
    f = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n%i == 0:
            f.append(i)
    return(f)
    
primes = []
    count = 0
    while count < 10:
        for j in range(1,1000):
            k = factors(j)
            if len(k) <= 2:
                primes.append(j)
                count += 1
    print(count)
```

The counts goes to 169 and, indeed, there are 169 prime numbers in the list generated, but I want it to stop at a certain number so I don't have to dig around to find, say, the 501st prime number.

I tried it another way, but the same thing happens. My guess is that the count and for j in range(1,1000) are interfering with one another.

```
primes = []
count = 0
while True:
    if count < 10:
        for j in range(1,1000):
            k = factors(j)
            if len(k) <= 2:
                primes.append(j)
                count += 1
    else:
        break
```

Comment: `for j in range(1,1000):` is going to execute exactly 999 times, no matter what.  The outer `while` loop's condition is not going to be evaluated again until the inner loop finishes.  If you want to stop at a particular `count` value, you need to check that each time it is incremented.

Comment: Computing *all* the factors of `n` when you only care if there are more then 2 is inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have a for loop inside you while loop. So it will always run from range(1,1000).

If you wish to have it quit when the count is reached you'll need to remove the while and break at the count

```
primes = []
count = 0
for j in range(1,1000):
    k = factors(j)
    if len(k) <= 2:
        primes.append(j)
        count += 1
    if count >= 10:
        break
print(count)
```

or remove the for

```
primes = []
count = 0
j = 0
while count < 10:
    k = factors(j)
    if len(k) <= 2:
        primes.append(j)
        count += 1
    j += 1
print(count)
```